# How to know if QLPreviewController successfully loaded a document/failed to load it?

Tags: objective-c, ios

My iOS app loads a variety of documents using QLPreviewController. My aim is to set a flag if the document loaded properly and show an error if it didn't.

Curiously the QLPreviewControllerDelegate protocol offers no callback to check this, nor does the QLPreviewController seem to throw any exception when I try to load an invalid file.

For the record, I tried loading an invalid PDF and it simply logged a message about not being able to find the header and displayed an empty file.

Can anyone please tell me how I can figure this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If establishing whether an item could be displayed beforehand works for you then a call to the following may be an option:

```
+(BOOL)canPreviewItem:(id<QLPreviewItem>) item
```

Comment: This method is useless. It merely checks the file extension to see if its compatible. If I rename a mkv as a pdf and pass its URL to this method, it still returns true.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the pointer.  I was coincidentally looking at the QLPreviewController myself and had assumed that method was a little more diligent about its work!  I'll leave the comment so that nobody else makes the same assumption.